# How to detect json.SyntaxError with errors.Is

Tags: go

I can't detect a json.SyntaxError while checking the error returned from a failed decoder.Decode operation!

[Here you can see a working example in playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/GQKRGR0Y80g)

As you can see the debugger confirm to me it's a pointer to a json.SyntaxError, but errors.Is can't detect it.

[image]

I checked the errors.Is implementation:

```
func Is(err, target error) bool {
    if target == nil {
        return err == target
    }

    isComparable := reflectlite.TypeOf(target).Comparable()
    for {
        if isComparable && err == target {
            return true
        }
        if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
            return true
        }
        // TODO: consider supporting target.Is(err). This would allow
        // user-definable predicates, but also may allow for coping with sloppy
        // APIs, thereby making it easier to get away with them.
        if err = Unwrap(err); err == nil {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And they are comparable (isComparable variable is true) but, when I would expect it to return true when it does `if isComparable && err == target {` it goes on...

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried with errors.As and it works.
I still do not understand well the difference.

Comment: errors.Is is **not** some kind of typechecking, it doesn't report whether repeated unwrapping err results in a value of the same type as the target, it literally compares if one of the unwrappings is identical to target. Your target is a pointer to a newly created json.Syntax error and nothing will have that same address. errors.As works differently, it is more a typechecking as it will set target if assignable (which (mod requires "equal" types). So errors.Is can be used only to check for defined sentinel errors like io.EOF or net/http.ErrBodyNotAllowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is currently happening is that you compare the memory address of a new `json.SyntaxError` to the error returned from `Decode`. As you have noticed this will never be true.

What you want to do is a bit different: check if `err` is of type `SyntaxError` and then work with that object directly. This is possible using [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), which basically check if the underlying type of an interface (`error` in this case) is a more specific type.

This is what [errors.As](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As) does. It populates a specific error type that you specify. Using this method, one lands at the following code:

```
if err != nil {
    var serr *json.SyntaxError
    
    if errors.As(err, &serr) {
        fmt.Println("Syntax error:", serr)
        fmt.Println("Offset:", serr.Offset)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Other error:", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this because json.SyntaxError is a struct?
So errors.Is works only on "strings" error?

Comment: @Cirelli94 `errors.Is` is typically used to compare to a specific error value defined by a package, e.g. the ones [declared by the `fs` package](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#pkg-variables). It also compares to so-called "wrapped" errors, which allows including more information while still including exactly that one defined error to compare to. The different ways of using errors are detailed in [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors). `errors.Is` works on all kinds of errors, but they need to be the same object in memory, not just be of the same type

Comment: @Cirelli94 think of errors now as "Russian Dolls" - if an error has a `Wrap` method then another error is inside of it (from a lower level call most likely). `fmt.Errorf` with the verb `"%w"` is the easiest way to wrap errors. From a callers perspective, the way to unwrap the "russian dolls" to see if it has your error is with `error.Is` & `error.As`. As X. has pointed out - `Is` does not work here since the error is not a fixed "sentinel error" - so better to match on type.

Comment: Read more at Dave Cheney's blog on [sentinel errors](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/errors)

Comment: Thank you very much @xarantolus and @colm.anseo!
I already read [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors) but I've not understood this question.
The problem here is that I was "hoping" to find the "sentinel error", while that error isn't inside the returned one, it's just of the same type. So I need `As`.
How should have noticed this before? Because I didn't find a fixed "sentinel error" in json.SyntaxError but it was a struct?

Comment: I'm very confused. This is the accepted answer, but it panics with `panic: errors: target must be a non-nil pointer`. Can this example be updated to not panic?

Comment: @jrwren can you show an example where it panics? [This](https://go.dev/play/p/iZpOpNRFENq) works just fine for me. Are you sure you're passing a pointer to the pointer to `errors.As`?