# How to handle json syntax error in a go test case?

Tags: go, go-testing

I'm testing a scenario where `json.Unmarshall` fails and returns

```
&json.SyntaxError{msg:"unexpected end of JSON input", Offset:0}
```

the code is like this:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(input, &data)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

test case is expecting this type of error:

```
{
...
errorType: &json.SyntaxError{},
...
}
```

the assertion is like this:

```
assert.Equal(t, tt.errorType, err)
```

which is failing because the error message is different:

```
expected: &json.SyntaxError{msg:"", Offset:0}
actual  : &json.SyntaxError{msg:"unexpected end of JSON input", Offset:0}
```

How can I handle this? Perhaps making use of `Error()` ?

Comment: related: [How to detect json.SyntaxError with errors.Is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598338/how-to-detect-json-syntaxerror-with-errors-is)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly it's [not possible](https://go.dev/play/p/FxBZ5BSb73N) to craft this sentinel error directly:

```
_ = &json.SyntaxError{msg: "unexpected end of JSON input", Offset: 0}  // msg field is not exported
```

the closest you can come is to check for the error *type*. To do this use [errors.As](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As)

```
var tt *json.SyntaxError

if errors.As(err, &tt) {
    log.Printf("Syntax Error: %v", tt)
} else if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Fatal: %#v", err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/mlqGN2ypwBs

You can check the `Offset` as that is public field. But to compare the non-public `msg` field, you'd need to use `err.Error()` - but this may be brittle as wording [may change](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/encoding/json/scanner.go;l=169) over time.

---

**Note:** [errors.Is](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) cannot be used here, as it only tests error equality: directly; or via [error.Unwrap](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Unwrap)-ing.

Since the [json.SyntaxError here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/encoding/json/scanner.go;l=169) is not wrapped - nor is it a [sentinel error](https://dave.cheney.net/tag/errors) - it cannot be matched via `errors.Is`.